# If $\mathcal{L}$ is an invertible sheaf on $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$, then is the restriction to the fibers constant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, projective-schemes

Let $X$ be a Noetherian regular scheme, and $\mathcal{E}$ a locally free sheaf of rank $n+1\geq 2$ on $X$. Let $\pi:\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})\to X$ be the natural morphism. Then for every $x\in X$, the fiber of $\pi$ over $x$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}_{k(x)}^n$. So if $\mathcal{L}$ is an invertible sheaf on $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$, then for every $x$ we get a unique integer $n_x=n_x(\mathcal{L})$ such that the restriction of $\mathcal{L}$ to $\mathbb{P}_{k(x)}^n$ is $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_{k(x)}^n}(n_x)$. Then is it true that $x\mapsto n_x$ is constant? How could one prove this elementarily?

Some thoughts: if $U=\operatorname{Spec}A$ is an affine open subset which trivializes $\mathcal{E}$, then $\pi^{-1}(U)\cong \mathbb{P}_A^n$. So if we can show the statement in this much simpler case, then we already obtain that $x\mapsto n_x$ is locally constant.

Comment: Small quibble: the dimension of the fibers of a projective bundle is $n-1$ if you start with a rank $n$ vector bundle.

Comment: Good catch, made the edit!

Comment: Also, I would suggest (if you haven't already) looking over the statements of the exercises in Hartshorne III.12, which are at least somewhat relevant.

Comment: Maybe you are referring to Exercise 12.5, which is to show that the Picard group of $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Pic}(X)\times \mathbb{Z}$, and certanly it would follow from (the proof of) it. The thing is, I want to use this for the solution of Exercise II.7.9, which is exactly this, but in a slightly different situation.